# How to convert file path in my computer to codebase?

Tags: java, html, japplet

I want to upload a `JApplet` in my blog but I don't know how to convert file path to `codebase`. (codebase=???). Does anyone know how? eg. Where does `D:/folder/file.class` go after `http://nameofyourblog.blogspot.com/` in codebase?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html) of Oracle? They are creating a JApplet and configuring all to see in the browser.

> CODEBASE = codebaseURL
>
> This OPTIONAL attribute specifies the base URL of the applet--the directory that contains the applet's code. If this attribute is not
>   specified, then the document's URL is used.